# how to send attachment files to email using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, email, email-attachments

Controller:

```html
public function sendemail(Request $request)
{
  $data = array(
    'name'=> $request->name,
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'text'=> $request->text,
        'category'=> $request->category,
        'company'=> $request->company,
        'number'=> $request->number
    );

  \Mail::send('AltHr/Portal/supportemail', $data, function ($message) use($data){

      $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
      $message->to('ra7veer@gmail.com')->subject($data['company'] . ' - ' .$data['category']);

      $message->attach($request->file('files')->getRealPath(), [
        'as' => $request->file('files')->getClientOriginalName(), 
        'mime' => $request->file('files')->getMimeType()
     ]);

  });
  
  return view('AltHr.Portal.support');
    }
```

Blade:

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
 <label>Attachment</label>
 <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="file_extension|image/*|media_type" multiple>
</div>
```

I tried doing a simple contact form to send to my email. Currently it works im able to send that email but without attachments. So i tried doing the code for the attachments but it dont seem to be working im getting error:

> Undefined variable: request

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#attachments

Comment: @DainisAbols yeah thats what i tried doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `$request` variable is undefined because `$request` variable is not available inside the function you need to passed this below

```
\Mail::send('AltHr/Portal/supportemail', compact('data'), function ($message) use($data, $request){ ....   });
```

Add the attr inside the form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form role="form" action="{{action('AltHr\Portal\PortalController@sendemail')}}" method="post" class="m-t-15" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ....
</form>
```

Try this code inside your `sendemail() method`

```
$data = array(
        'name'=> $request->name,
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'text'=> $request->text,
        'category'=> $request->category,
        'company'=> $request->company,
        'number'=> $request->number
    );
    $files = $request->file('files');
    \Mail::send('AltHr/Portal/supportemail', compact('data'), function ($message) use($data, $files){    
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('nuru7495@gmail.com')->subject($data['company'] . ' - ' .$data['category']);

        if(count($files) > 0) {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                $message->attach($file->getRealPath(), array(
                    'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(), // If you want you can chnage original name to custom name      
                    'mime' => $file->getMimeType())
                );
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$emails = ['email address 1', 'email address 2'];
$files = ['url 1','url 2'];
Mail::send('emails.welcome', [], function($message) use ($emails, $files)
{
    $message->to($emails)->subject('This is test e-mail');
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $message->attach($file);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_to_attach = 'freestuff/free-file.pdf';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'free-file.pdf' );
```

use AddAttactment

Answer (score 1):

```
      Mail::send('mail', array('type'=>'AspirantsSelect','AspirantsSelectSms'=>$smg), function($message) use($emailA,$pic)
                        {
                            $message->to($emailA)->subject('Aspirants Selection');
                            $message->attach($pic);
                        });
```